# Randomize the elements of an array

Tags: php, arrays, random

I have an array with a unknown number of elements.
I'd like to randomize its elements so that each time i display it, its elements to be displayed in random order.
now i do:

```
 foreach($photos['data'] as $photo)
{ echo $photo; }
```

is there any way to randomize the elements of $photos['data'] array?
thanks!

Comment: [`shuffle`](http://php.net/shuffle)`($photos['data'])` ?

Comment: http://php.net/shuffle

Comment: Use either `shuffle` (already suggested) or [`array_rand`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php). The latter does not manipulates with array that was passed but returns shuffled array, also second parameters gives you possibility to chose how many items should be returned.

Comment: if i use shuffle like $shuf = $photos['data'] then , parsing $shuf returns empty array

Comment: @dana `shuffle` does not return array, it shuffles array that was passed since array is passed by reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [shuffle](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) function:

For example:

```
<?php
suffle($photos['data'];
foreach ($photos['data'] as $photo) {
  echo $photo;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The shuffle() function randomizes the order of the elements in the array. More more info, refer [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php).

This function assigns new keys for the elements in the array. Existing keys will be removed.

This function returns TRUE on success, or FALSE on failure.

For EG :

```
<?php
$my_array = array("a" => "Dog", "b" => "Cat", "c" => "Horse");

shuffle($my_array);
print_r($my_array);
?>
```

In your case :

```
<?php
suffle($photos['data']);
print_r($photos['data']);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $items[array_rand($items)];
```

array_rand() Gone through this function.It is best suitalbe option for your question

Answer (score -1):

use `sort()` function.
see link for further help http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php
think it will help you. thanks.